# Is a totally bounded set necessarily closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

If A is a totally bounded set in metric space X, then A is closed in X? If not, can you show me some examples?

Comment: No. $(0,1)$ is totally bounded in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Any subset of a totally bounded set is also totally bounded.

Comment: To explore further this idea: any precompact open set in $\Bbb R^n$ is totally bounded.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: what is precompact?

Comment: @Frank_W the set is precompact if its closure is compact.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy:awesomeeeee. So totally bounded set can be one kind of them(precompact sets), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is answered in comments, but just to record an actual answer:

*No*, a totally bounded subset needn't be closed.

E.g. any subset of a totally bounded set is totally bounded (almost by definition), and any non-closed subset of a totally bounded set gives an example.

E.g. in $\mathbb R^n$, totally bounded is simply the same as bounded, and
there are lots of non-closed bounded sets.  E.g. (as noted in comments) the interval $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R$.  Another example is the set of points $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with $x,y \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$. I'm sure you can think of many more: just take any closed bounded set and then remove some of its limit points.

---

Often the concept of totally bounded comes up in the context of ``totally bounded and complete iff compact''.  When thinking  about this, you can think of *totally bounded* as generalizing the notion of bounded from $\mathbb R^n$ to an arbitrary metric space, and *complete* as generalizing closed from $\mathbb R^n$ to an arbitrary metric space.  (Note that for a subset of a complete metric space, complete is equivalent to closed, and $\mathbb R^n$ is complete.  So, if the ambient metric space is complete, then we can say that "totally bounded and closed" is equivalent to compact, which looks more like the traditional Heine-Borel theorem for $\mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: The definition of a compact set is every open cover has a finite subcover. But why does "every open cover has a finite subcover" imply the metric space being complete?

Comment: Dear Frank W, This is a standard result.  If you google "compact implies complete" I'm sure you'll find plenty of links dealing with this.  Regards,

Comment: really appreciate your kindness and patience, Matt E^_^